# Как вернуть NULL, если запрос не выдаст ответа

Tags: mysql

Имею таблицу

```
ID, SALARY
1   100
2   200
3   300
```

Нужно найти второе по величине значение `salary`, если ничего не найдено, то вывести `NULL`.
Второе значение я нашел вот так

```
SELECT Salary
FROM Employee
ORDER BY salary
LIMIT 1,1;
```

А как вывести `NULL`, если допустим таблица пуста я не понимаю

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT COALESCE((SELECT Salary
                 FROM Employee
                 ORDER BY salary
                 LIMIT 1,1)) SALARY;
```

PS. COALESCE() в принципе нужен, чтобы вместо NULL вывести вменяемое значение (скажем, "нет данных"). Если устраивает NULL, то достаточно `SELECT (SELECT ...)`.

Comment: SELECT (SELECT Salary
 FROM Employee
 ORDER BY salary
 LIMIT 1,1); 
Так? Так выводит в строке NULL, но в поле прописывается теперь весь запрос в скобках

Comment: @Tunix *в поле прописывается теперь весь запрос в скобках* :facepalm: Если выходному полю не присвоен алиас, то в качестве алиаса используется текст выражения поля.